# Google Maps API: Trigger a function when visible area changes

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a search page like Airbnb's that shows a map and a result pane. I want my result list to update as the map is panned or zoomed.

The flow I want:

1. User pans or zooms the map.
2. Search function runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure out my solution. Now I'm using `bound_changed` and `zoom_changed` events to trigger my search function.

```
function search() {
    // The search function
}

var map
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.7563309, 100.5017651),
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    })
    // Listen for events on the map
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', search)
    map.addListener('zoom_changed', search)
}
```